# Disable output file settings dialog when using text export

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, fastreport

Using the [frxSimpleTextExport](https://www.fast-report.com/documentation/UserMan/index.html?export_to_text_format.htm) component  I can save my report as a `.txt` file, but as soon as I click on the `Save as txt` button, an unwanted dialog appears.

[image]

How can I make this windows to not appear and let the user see only the `SaveDialog`, which is opened after clicking OK here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable "Export to text" dialog(The first one in your question):

Set `frxSimpleTextExport.ShowDialog` property to false:

```
 frxSimpleTextExport.ShowDialog := False;
```

Now this dialog window will not appear but `SaveDialog` will disappear also.
To show 'SaveDialog' drop `TSaveDialog` on your form and in `frxSimpleTextExport BeginExport` event write :

```
procedure TForm7.frxSimpleTextExport1BeginExport(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute() then
    begin
      frxSimpleTextExport1.FileName := SaveDialog1.FileName;
    end;
end;
```